# output text in bold font using SED editor In unix script

Tags: unix, sed

hi I want to write a unix script, while using the SED editor, to output the text, in this case a variable, to the result file but highlighted it in bold, is it possible to do that? can you tell me how?

eg. in `text.txt`

Code:

```
sed '$ a\
'$variable'
     ' <text.txt >text2.txt
```

so it will add the variable after the last line in the `text.txt` file, but preferably in bold

Thanks
Robert

Comment: What do you mean "in bold"? Is it a plain ASCII file, or does it have some kind of internal format, like an HTML document?

Comment: Basically I want to output a text (log) file but with some information highlighted to ease reading

Comment: What are you using to read the file?

Comment: Any normal editor like nedit or emacs, if that is possible?

Answer (score -1):

A plain text file has no such thing as bold. Bold is a way of *displaying* text. Depending on what tool you use to display the text, you may be able to mark a word in a way that tells the tool to display it in bold. There are different ways to do this, which different tools recognize:

```
HTML tag, recognized by many browsers and editors:
"foo" => "<b>foo</b>"

Enriched text tag, recognized by emacs in enriched-mode and some email tools
"foo" => "<bold>foo</bold>"
```

You should try it by hand before you try to do it automatically.

Suppose you decide on HTML. Now to add the line to the end of a file using sed:

```
sed '$a\
<b>$variable</b>
' text.txt > text2.txt
```